# typeaheadjs to update 2 inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js

I'm trying to find a way to update my 2 inputs with one select of typeaheadjs. Is that possible or I need to create my own dropdown?

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" data-tah id="width">
<input type="text" data-tah id="height">
```

**JS**

```
$('input[data-tah]').typeahead({                              
  name: 'Update 2 values',
  valueKey: "can't be an array...",                                                    
  prefetch: 'something.json',                                             
  template: [                                                                 
    '<p class="tah-height">{{height}}"</p>x',                              
    '<p class="tah-width">{{width}}"</p>',                                                               
  ].join(''),
  /*No onSelect method...*/                                                  
});
```

So I have a dropDown with  like

```
36"x24"
18"x24"
...
```

if I click on the first one I want the `input#width` to be 36 and `input#height` 24.

Answer (score 0):

The typeahead method will probably only work on the first element in the set of matched elements, like most jQuery methods. To add functionality to both inputs, you'll want to use the jQuery `.each()` function.

```
$('input[data-tah]').each(function() {
    $(this).typeahead({
         ...
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you take 2 inputs and concatenate them? Pass the string into typeaheadjs?? I don`t think I fully understand the question.

Comment: I added some explanation at the end.